# Printing a string List from another task while one task adds to the list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

I have an interaction where I am adding to a List from one task while i perform an operation (a log), and I want a win forms background worker to print new additions to this list as it runs

The call to the api is

```cs
List<string> log = new List();
obj.PerformOperation(value, out log);
```

And I was hoping that I could print to the GUI text box the new additions to the list as I go, I tired something like this but it doesn't work

```cs
private void configWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> log = new List<string>();
    logWorker.RunWorkerAsync(log);
    obj.PerformOperation(value, out log);
}

private void logWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    List<string> log = e.Argument as List<string>;
    int log_index = 0;
    do
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
            if (log.Count > log_index)
            {
                do
                {
                    logTextBox.RecordLog(log[log_index++]);
                } while (log_index < log.Count);
            }
        }));
    } while (!worker.CancellationPending);
}
```

The background worker loops but it doesn't seem to update the text box. Could anyone help me with how to perform this without modifying the api call?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try observables. Maybe following gives you some ideas? Get notified, print results. No need to constantly iterate collection in the background.

```
private void RunIt()
{
    var cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cancelTokenSource.Token;

    var things = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    things.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            foreach (var item in args.NewItems)
                BeginInvoke((Action) (() => logTextBox.Text += $@"{item}{Environment.NewLine}"));
    };
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            things.Add(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }, token);
}
```

Comment: This looks very much like what I am looking for, but the API call has an out type of List<string>. Simply changing the type of log doesn't seem to work so It doesn't seem they are interchangeable/generic :/